# How can I force overlay to show when use v-dialog?

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js, overlay

I have a v-dialog that opens when page is loaded. Somehow overlay is lost. The behavior is very similar to this bug report: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7798
But in my case overlay works when v-dialog loads after several seconds of page loading, and overlay is lost only when v-dialog is loaded from the very beginning. So I have to find the way to fix it or to force overlay to be shown together with dialog.
I tried to work with v-overlay (to wrap dialog content there), but it's content is not shown as well, if we try to do this while page is loading.

So how can I fix this or force overlay to work?

Comment: please share the code of that dialog

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've placed standard v-dialog ( https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101&prefill_data_id=76ef6a50-d1a4-0138-cfea-02420aff0008&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdialogs%2F ) from vuetify documentation and it had the same result: no overlay when opened first several seconds after page loaded.

Comment: the provided codepen example is empty

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, weird, link is right. but seems it's opening right onlu from vuetify page. Anyway it's from here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/ (I tried first example with Google's location service)

Comment: when you open a codepen from vuetify docs you should save it to give it an unique url

Comment: the first example is shown with overlay

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim they work with overlay on the vuetify page. And they work in code pen when I try to mount dialog opening. The problem is that my page is more heavy, it loads longer and I guess that's the reason why I'm loosing overlay when dialog opens together with the page

Comment: So the question is - how can I force overlay to open with the dialog, since it's not working automatically in my case

Comment: it looks like a performance issue in your app, try to place that dialog in the root component

Comment: Placing dialog right in App.vue goes to the same result: no overlay when enable dialog from mounted()

Comment: And overlay is shown if I set a timeout 5s before opening the dialog